# Parsing one column with 5 didgits integers as date format while reading excel file

Tags: r, datetime-format, lubridate, zoo, openxlsx

For an excel file (download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/u5reyejv0b5xcplznsbkn/sample_data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=y9orwgqxr63dxbwka7y8mx3cj)):

[image]

```
df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx('sample_data.xlsx', sheet='Sheet1', colNames=TRUE)
df
```

Output:

```
   date  value
1 43861   5.70
2 43890 -13.89
3 43921 -49.68
4 43951 -62.81
```

I try to convert date column to a normal date format:

```
> df %>% 
+   mutate(date=as.Date(date, origin = "1970-01-01"))
        date  value
1 2090-02-01   5.70
2 2090-03-02 -13.89
3 2090-04-02 -49.68
4 2090-05-02 -62.81

> df %>% 
+   mutate(date=as.Date(date, origin = "1910-01-01"))
        date  value
1 2030-02-01   5.70
2 2030-03-02 -13.89
3 2030-04-02 -49.68
4 2030-05-02 -62.81
```

I tested with `1970-01-01` and `1910-01-01` as value for `origin` parameter, the dates in the output seems incorrect (`43861` has been convert to `2090-02-01` and `2030-02-01`, which should be `2020-01-31`).

Comment: Excel dates are messed up. Usually you need to do `origin="1899-12-30"` but it's  [more complicated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system) in some cases and system-dependent.

Comment: It's quite confusing, for other excel files with dates columns, I did't meet this issue. I manually convert them to short date under same procedure in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin` has to be *inside* the `as.Date` call.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30"))
#>         date  value
#> 1 2020-01-31   5.70
#> 2 2020-02-29 -13.89
#> 3 2020-03-31 -49.68
#> 4 2020-04-30 -62.81
```

Comment: @ahbon `as.Date("2020-01-31") - 43861`

Comment: `> as.Date(43861) [1] "2090-02-01"`, while my lap returns `2090-02-01`. In fact, I try to know how do u find `origin` should be set as `1899-12-30`, not other date. It does works, thanks for your help.